# Can I add support for iPad while my application uses iPhone as target device family. Will it get rejected?

Tags: iphone

My application is in appstore currently it supports only for iPhone/iPod and runs on iPad in 1x and 2x mode. Can I change target device family to universal and add dummy screenshot for iPad and submit it on app store for iPhone/iPad without adding xib's for iPad.

Will it get rejected?

Comment: I don't think it will get rejected

Comment: You can make a universal app without adding xibs for iPad anyway. You don't *need* to have an iPad xib, just the autoscaling.

Answer (score 1):

If you mark it as a universal app, but don't actually support iPad (e.g it runs in crappy scaled mode) then it will be rejected, and rightly so. iPad support means it runs *natively* on the iPad. Mocked up screenshots that don't actually reflect the app isn't a good idea either.

Leave it as it is until you've built proper iPad support. Then change it to universal.

Answer (score 0):

You need add all stuff about ipad dimensions including images.